# How can I programmatically create a process snapshot on windows/unix?

Tags: go, memory, process, snapshot, dump

I am creating a Golang program that creates a process and then should be able to suspend it.

To make it more memory efficient, I would need my program to be able to dump the memory of the process to disk and reload it only when needed.

I cannot find any info here on Stack Overflow and also GitHub is not helping.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to answer this with the limited info..

> To make it more memory efficient, I would need my program to be able to dump the memory of the process to disk and reload it only when needed.

This is generally something handled by your operating system (scheduler, memory management) controlling what processes are currently running / suspended / etc. and what memory needs to be paged in / out. Trying to implement the equivalent is quite complex, error prone, and likely to be less performant. Why do you believe you need to implement this yourself?

If you are building a program and want to have explicit control about whether it should be considered runnable or not, you could create a process which forks (creating two total processes), and have the parent process suspend and resume the child process using signals:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: `could create a process which forks (creating two total processes), and have the parent process suspend and resume the child process using signals` this is exacly what I am doing now and was wondering if it was possible to dump/reload an entire process to disk (avoiding keeping it in ram)